# Separate Login & Registration page in Woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

How to separate login and registration page in woo-commerce storefront theme, have tried copy `login-form.php` and paste it and rename as `register.php`, added link in login Login page and inserted some code in template `functions.php` file but not working.

Used Woo-commerce Login/Signup plugin by Phoenix but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two pages with this shortcode and hide register form from one page and login form from another page by css.

```
[woocommerce_my_account]
```

Comment: I want to separate Login and Register page that means Login option in Other page and Register option on another page.

Comment: adding [woocommerce_my_account] will create both options on the single page

Comment: You can create two pages with this shortcode and hide register form from one page and login form from another page by css.

Comment: @KAGGDesign above shortcode giving common form for login and register. question is how to separate the login and registration forms.

Comment: @PramodKharade Especially for you I have created 2 pages on my test site: http://test.kagg.eu/wc-login/ and http://test.kagg.eu/wc-registrarion/. If you cannot read my answer properly, and understand what is written there (try to find word `css` again), it is better not to comment, and, moreover, to downvote

Comment: @KAGGDesign I understood your solution but that solution is not right by hiding register and login page by css. if you will hide the pages by css then there is performance impact. Instead of it you can make condition page in same page like: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/woocommerce-login-registration-on-separate-pages

Comment: @PramodKharade "performance impact" is ridiculous here, some tens of milliseconds. Your first comment clearly says that you did *not* understand my answer, as you pointed on "how to separate the login and registration form". Next time better propose your own answer, which can be compared and downvoted.